# Concept of Inserting at last in LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I have `Link1 class` to create the link and display link data,
`LinkedList1` to create the list and inserting elements in LinkedList.And `singleLinkedList` class to call the methods of `addFirst` and `addLast.`
Implementation details are below.**The only issue is in the pointer which should be set for the last link after inserting data at the last element in `addlast` method.**

**Link1 class implementation**

```
class Link1{

    public String str;
    public Link1 forward;

    public Link1(String str){
        this.str=str;
        this.forward=null;
    }
    public void displayLink1(){
        System.out.println("Link DATA::"+str);
    }
}
```

**LinkList1 class implementation**

```
class LinkedList1{
    public Link1 first;
    public LinkedList1(){
        first=null;
    }
    public boolean isEmplty(){
        return first==null;
    }
    public void addFirst(String str){
        Link1 newLink=new Link1(str);
        newLink.forward=first;
        first=newLink;
    }
    public Link1 deleteFirst(){
        Link1 temp=first;
        first=first.forward;
        return temp;
    }
    public void insertLast(String str){
        Link1 current=first;
        Link1 last=first;
        Link1 newLinkLast=new Link1(str);
        while(current!=null){   
        current=current.forward;
            if(current==null);
            {
            last=current.forward;            //trying to reach to end of the linkedlist     
            break;
            }
        }
          newLinkLast.forward=last;                      //the last.displayLink is having the correct data evertime this is method getting called.But this is not going to my LinkedList
    //COMMENTED****last.forward=newLinkLast              //SOMETHING IS MESSED HERE,if i add one works perfect but the whole list gets messed up,including the elements added by insertFirst            
           last=newLinkLast;               
        last.displayLink1();                      //Just for testing i am printing the value of this link,which is coming correct everytime i call this method.
    }
    public void displayOB(){
        Link1 current=first;
        while(current!=null){
            current.displayLink1();
            current=current.forward;
        }
    }
}
```

**singleLinkedList implementation**

public class singleLinkedList {

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList1 ll=new LinkedList1();

        ll.addFirst("A");
        ll.addFirst("B");
        ll.addFirst("C");

        ll.addFirst("d");
        ll.addFirst("e");
        ll.addFirst("f");

        ll.addFirst("x");
        ll.addFirst("y");
        ll.addFirst("z");

    ll.insertLast("Insert me at End 1");
    ll.insertLast("Insert me at End 2");
    ll.insertLast("Insert Again");

        ll.displayOB();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
 **for 1st line which is newLinkLast.forward=last**

```
Link DATA::Insert me at End 1     //this is the displayLink method called in insertLast

Link DATA::Insert me at End 2     //this is the displayLink method called in insertLast

Link DATA::Insert Again           //this is the displayLink method called in insertLast

Link DATA::z
Link DATA::y
Link DATA::x
Link DATA::f
Link DATA::e
Link DATA::d
Link DATA::C
Link DATA::B
Link DATA::A
```

**for 2nd COMMENTED LINE line which is newLinkLast.forward=last**

```
Link DATA::Insert me at End 1            //this is the displayLink method called in insertLast
Link DATA::Insert me at End 2            //this is the displayLink method called in insertLast

Link DATA::Insert Again                  //this is the displayLink method called in insertLast

Link DATA::z
Link DATA::y
Link DATA::x
Link DATA::Insert Again
```

**Results Expected**
the insert last should insert element at last any number of times.

Comment: any Help!!!Is the question not posted properly? information not enough.Please let me know.I wish to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
       if(current!=null) //removed comma, changed == to !=
       {
        last=current.forward;             
        break;
       }
```

Comment: bigGuy:Can you please explain how it would make me reach the end of my LinkedList?What i am trying there is to reach the end and store that value in last and break.